# Can't Print String Array Element

Tags: c++

Whenever I try to run this program it returns an error saying:

> no operator "<<" matches these operands

Also note that the program only runs into this problem in the `getChoice()` function.

```
#include <iostream>
#include "utilities.h"

using namespace std;

int getChoice(string inChoices[]){
    int numOfChoices = sizeof(inChoices) / sizeof(inChoices[0]);
    string x = inChoices[0];
    string y = inChoices[1];
    cout << x << endl << y << endl;
    return numOfChoices;
}

int main()
{
    string choices[2] = { "Happy Day", "Even Better Day" };
    cout << utilities::getChoice(choices) << endl;

    cout << endl << sizeof(choices) / sizeof(choices[0]) << endl;
}
```

Comment: You forgot to `#include <string>`.

Answer (score 1):

You need also to include the `string` header:

```
#include <string>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to `#include <string>`

And your calculation of `numOfChoices` in `getChoice()` is wrong, since the parameter `inChoices` is actually a "pointer to string" instead of "array of strings".

Comment: No problem for the `getChoice()`.

Comment: @herohuyongtao, No syntactic problem, but there is a logic error.