# Can't Print string Array Element in C++

Tags: c++

Whenever I try to run this program it returns an error saying:

> no operator "<<" matches these operands

Also note that the program only runs into this problem in the getChoice() function; `main()` seems to work just fine.

> ```
> #include <iostream>
>
> using namespace std;
>
> int getChoice(string inChoices[]){
>     int numOfChoices = sizeof(inChoices) / sizeof(inChoices[0]);
>     cout << inChoices[0] << endl << inChoices[1] << endl;
>     return numOfChoices;
> }
>
> int main()
> {
>     string choices[2] = { "Happy Day", "Even Better Day" };
>     cout << getChoice(choices) << endl;
>
>     cout << endl << sizeof(choices) / sizeof(choices[0]) << endl;
> }
> ```

Comment: Why you ask the exact same question twice within an hour?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21656386/cant-print-string-array-element

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot

```
#include <string>
```